# Can "Hence" be used like conjunction?

Tags: word-usage

Now I am writing a scientific paper.
My professor wrote this sentence at first:

*Due to its ~ characteristics, microwave energy promotes ~ (list of advantages), hence the properties of ~ can be enhanced through microwave irradiation.*

As far as I know, however, "hence" is not a conjunction, so it cannot bring a clause after it like above sentence.
So, I tried to correct the sentence like this:

*Due to its ~ characteristics, microwave energy promotes ~, hence the enhancement of the properties of ~.*

However, I was able to find a lot of sentences using "hence" like conjunction in google search and even in this site.
So, here is a question:

- Can "hence" be used like conjunction as it used in the first sentence? (even though it is incorrect grammatically, is it used in this way commonly?)
- If not, does my correction make sense?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hence`, like `therefore`, can be used as a [conjunctive adverb or adverbial conjunction](https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/gram_conj_adv.html.). Though some frown on the use of conjunctive adverbs and others consider their [punctuation problematic](https://www.iup.edu/writingcenter/writing-resources/grammar/common-problems-with-however,-therefore,-and-similar-words/), they are used in colloquial English. However, the example you provide might be better with a semicolon, rather than full-stop (period), before `hence`.